# What is the correct Bogoliubov transformation for a SDW (spin density wave) Hamiltonian in the FBZ (First Brillouin Zone)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian

The Hamiltonian for a   Antiferromagement with Spin Density Wave (SDW) (in the Reduced Brillouin Zone (RBZ))is written as-
\begin{eqnarray}  
H_{\mathbf{k}\in RBZ}=\sum\limits_{\mathbf{k} \in RBZ}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{\sigma}}\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}^{\dagger}& d_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}^{\dagger}\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\xi_{\mathbf{k}} & sgn(\sigma) M\\
sgn(\sigma) M &  \xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}\\
d_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{1}
\label{HRBZ}
\end{eqnarray}
We assume that the SDW is commensurate i.e $2\mathbf{Q}=G$, for example in a 2d square lattice $\mathbf{Q}=(\pi/a,\pi/a)=\mathbf{G}/2$, where $\mathbf{G}$ is the reciprocal lattice vector. The $RBZ$ has the property that for each $\mathbf{k}\in RBZ$ , $\mathbf{k+Q}\in FBZ.$ Therefore in the spirit of the reduced zone scheme we ascribe the state created by $c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k+Q}}$ also to $\mathbf{k}$ by introducing the new fermion creation operator $d^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k}}=c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k+Q}}$.In the following we assume $sgn(\sigma)=1\Rightarrow\sigma=\uparrow $  and $M$ to be real.

The energy eigenvalues of (\ref{HRBZ}) are $E^{\alpha}_{\mathbf{k}}=\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{+}+ \Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}$ and $E^{\beta}_{\mathbf{k}}=\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{+}- \Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}$ where $\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}= \sqrt{(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})^2+ (\sigma M)^2},\quad\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(\xi_{\mathbf{k}} \pm\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}})$.

The eigenvector corresponding to $E^{\alpha}_{\mathbf{k}}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}u_{\mathbf{k}}\\v_{\mathbf{k}}\end{bmatrix}$, whereas the
eigenvector corresponding to $E^{\beta}_{\mathbf{k}}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}-v_{\mathbf{k}}\\u_{\mathbf{k}}\end{bmatrix}$.The coloumns of the  Bogoliubov transformation matrix is constructed from the eigenvectors of (\ref{HRBZ}), which is given by,
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k}}\\
d_{\mathbf{k}}\\
\end{bmatrix}&=& \begin{bmatrix}
u_{\mathbf{k}} & -v_{\mathbf{k}} \\
v_{\mathbf{k}}&  u_{\mathbf{k}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}\\
\beta_{\mathbf{k}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{2}
\label{BT}
\end{eqnarray}
where $u_{\mathbf{k}}$ and $v_{\mathbf{k}}$ are

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
u_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+ \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
v_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1- \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}
\label{uv}
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore we start with two energy bands $c_{\mathbf{k}}$ and
$d_{\mathbf{k}}$ for each $\mathbf{k}$, the SDW opens gaps along the edge of the RBZ, we finally end with two new bands  $E^{\alpha}_{\mathbf{k}}$ and  $E^{\beta}_{\mathbf{k}}$ for each $\mathbf{k}$. In the reduced Brillouin zone all of the above is well known. See

*Lecture Notes on Electron Correlation and Magnetism by Patrik Fazekas page 365-366*

*Fundamentals of The Physics of Solids vol. III by Jeno Solyom, page 348-352*

**My question is how to construct the Bogoliubov transformation in the First Brillouin Zone (FBZ)(instead of the RBZ) to diagonalize \ref{HFBZ} ?** The Hamiltonian in the FBZ is 
\begin{eqnarray}
H_{\mathbf{k}\in FBZ} &=&\sum\limits_{\mathbf{k} \in FBZ}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{\sigma}} \begin{bmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}^{\dagger}& c_{\mathbf{k+Q}\sigma}^{\dagger}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_{\mathbf{k}} & sgn(\sigma) M   \\
sgn(\sigma) M &  \xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}\\
c_{\mathbf{k+Q}\sigma}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{4}
\label{HFBZ}
\end{eqnarray}

Should the two energy eigenvalues of \ref{HFBZ} be written as  $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k}}=\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{+}+sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}) \Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}$ and $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k+Q}}=\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{+}+sgn( \xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k+Q}}$ ? My reasoning behind this is the following- since we start with one energy band $c_{\mathbf{k}}$ for each $\mathbf{k}$, the SDW opens gaps along the edge of the RBZ, we finally end with one band $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k}}$ for each $\mathbf{k}$.

We should be able to construct the coloumns of the  Bogoliubov transformation matrix from the eigenvectors of \ref{HFBZ}, corresponding to energy eigenvalues $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k}}$ and $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k+Q}}$ above. (Again assume $sgn(\sigma)=1$ i.e  $\sigma=\uparrow$  and $M$ to be real)
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k}}\\
c_{\mathbf{k+Q}}\\
\end{bmatrix}&=& \begin{bmatrix}
u_{\mathbf{k}} & v_{\mathbf{k+Q}}  \\
v_{\mathbf{k}}&  u_{\mathbf{k+Q}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}\\
\gamma_{\mathbf{k+Q}\sigma}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{5}
\label{BT2} 
\end{eqnarray}

If I compute the eigenvectors I get 
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
u_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+ \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
v_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1- \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
u_{\mathbf{k+Q}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+ \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
v_{\mathbf{k+Q}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1- \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k+Q}}}\bigg)}\\
\end{aligned}
\tag{6}
\label{uv2}
\end{eqnarray}
Are these the correct u's and v's ? The strange thing is , if I write $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k+Q}}=\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{+}+sgn( \xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k+Q}}$ as $E^{\gamma}_{\mathbf{k+Q}}=\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{+}-sgn( \xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}$ which is the same thing because  $\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{+}=\xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{+}$, $sgn( \xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})=-sgn( \xi_{\mathbf{k+Q}}^{-})$ and $\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}=\Lambda_{\mathbf{k+Q}} $ , I get the following 
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
u_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+ \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
v_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1- \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}\\
u_{\mathbf{k+Q}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+ \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k}}}\bigg)}=u_{\mathbf{k}} \\
v_{\mathbf{k+Q}} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1- \frac{\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-}}{sgn(\xi_{\mathbf{k}}^{-})\Lambda_{\mathbf{k+Q}}}\bigg)}= -v_{\mathbf{k}} \\
\end{aligned}
\tag{7}
\label{uv3}
\end{eqnarray}
**Which of the above u,v's /transformations \ref{uv2} or \ref{uv3} is correct ? What is is the correct relationship between $v_{\mathbf{k}}$ and $v_{\mathbf{k+Q}}$ in the FBZ ?**